# Why is margin stretching the body's width?

Tags: css

I'm trying to use margin on an element, but it ends up stretching the body's width. Can find the reason why.

```
.navbar {
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;

  background: $c-white;
  margin: 0.5rem;
}
```

Comment: Are you intending to do padding instead of margin? Can you screenshot an example of what you are trying to do and what is happening?

Comment: *it ends up stretching the body's width.* --> you are probably getting an horizontal scroll, right? ... instead of margin put the value inside left/right